# Comparing permalink to url

Tags: permalinks

I'm trying to compare the permalink with a url and then output stuff depending if they match. At the moment I have the code below. On the page it's visibly showing that the permalink and the url (i.e $company) match yet it's outputting "don't show news articles".

Where am I going wrong?

```
<p>permalink of current page: <?php $link = get_permalink(); echo $link; ?></p>
<?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news' ) ); ?>
    <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>                           
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('featured_companies')): ?>
            <p>url of linked page: <?php $company = the_sub_field('featured_company'); ?></p>
            <?php  if ($link == $company) { ?>
                show news articles
            <?php } else { ?>
                don't show news articles
            <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my brain nearly exploded with this, solved the problem using the relationship field and lot's of loops:

```
<h2>Latest News</h2>    
<?php $link = get_the_title(); ?>
<?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'news' ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>  
    <?php $post_link = get_post_permalink(); ?>                        
        <?php  if (get_field('featured_companies') != "") { ?>
            <?php foreach(get_field('featured_companies') as $post): ?>
                <?php $company = get_the_title($post_object->ID); ?>
                <?php if ($company == $link) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $post_link; ?>">News item 1</a>
                <?php } ?> 
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using [`get_sub_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_sub_field/), not `the_sub_field()` to set `$company`. `the_sub_field()` has no return, it just `echo`s the value, whereas `get_sub_field()` returns the value (but does not echo it).